# Can't download numpy and tensorflow to python 3.5

Tags: numpy, tensorflow, python-3.5, python-3.6

I have been trying to download tensorflow, and numpy so that they will work when I run them in python 3.5 idle ( the newest model that tensorflow seems to work with). I have both python 3.6 and 3.5 downloaded and I can't seem to make anything that I download( numpy so far) apply to anything but 3.6. I'm not sure if this has something to do with the path that I am calling them through command line, but I was wondering if there was an answer to this situation.

Comment: How do you install your libraries? Which OS do you have? What are the full tracebacks of your error messages? Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Does [`python3.5 -m pip install tensorflow`](https://docs.python.org/3/installing/index.html#basic-usage) work? Or virtualenv is always good (and you can specify a specific Python interpreter to use).

Answer (score 1):

1] Using `pip` package manager

- Use `pip` to install numpy for you :  `pip install numpy`
- If you do not have pip you can install it by following command : `python get-pip.py`
- Use `pip` to install tensorflow for you: `pip install tensorflow`

2] Using **Anaconda** or **Miniconda** (RECOMMENDED)

- Install [Anaconda](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/install/download.html) or [Miniconda](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/install/download.html)
- `conda` is the package manager for Anaconda and Miniconda
- Open the Conda prompt
- Anaconda comes with `numpy` package so no need to explicitly install `numpy`
- In case if you have downloaded Miniconda then you have to install `numpy` I guess. Run the following command to install numpy : `conda install numpy`
- Run the following command to install tensorflow :`conda install -c conda-forge tensorflow` or simply `conda install tensorflow`
- Anaconda also comes with it's own `pip`. You can use Anaconda's pip to install tensorflow by running `pip install tensorflow`

===========================================================================

- By any chance if you get an error in the terminal saying that `"command" is not recognized as an internal or external command` which means you have not specified the absolute path of `pip` or `python` or `conda`
- One solution to the above error can be to add the path of python, pip and anaconda as an environmental variable if you are on windows
- If you are on Linux you can add the path of python, pip and anaconda to the `PATH` variable by `export PATH=$PATH:/path/to/dir`